Huge memory consumption with SD3.5-medium
I have a g4dn.xlarge AWS GPU instance, it has 16GB memory + 48GB swap, and a Tesla T4 GPU Instance with 16GB vRAM.
According to the stability blog, it should be sufficient to run SD3.5 Medium model.

So I downloaded the model from hugging face, and launched my test program.
At first I see the memory and swap goes up, consumed in total ~30GB memory. Then the system memory started to go down, and Nvidia GPU memory usage grows slowly. Then later it failed with memory allocation issue. It failed to allocate more memory after ~15GB GPU memory is allocated.
My questions are,

Is it normal to consume that much of memory? Both system and GPU level.
What's wrong with my program?

Attached my source code,
import os
import json
import torch

from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline

pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("./stable-diffusion-3.5-medium/")
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print('use cuda')
    pipe = pipe.to("cuda")
elif torch.mps.is_available():
    print('use mps')
    pipe = pipe.to('mps')
else:
    print('use cpu')

data = []
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

os.makedirs('output', exist_ok=True)
for row in data:
    prompt   = row['prompt']
    filename = 'output/%s.png' % (row['uuid'])
    height   = 1280
    width    = 1280
    
    if row['aspect_ratio'] == '16:9':
        width = 720
    elif row['aspect_ratio'] == '9:16':
        width = 720
        height = 1280
    
    print('saving', filename)
    image = pipe(prompt, height=height, width=width).images[0]
    image.save(filename)



I can't comment so I am submitting my thoughts as an answer.
first, i don't think anything is wrong with your code.
Also to provide more context:

"At first I see the memory and swap goes up, consumed in total ~30GB
memory."

this is probably from the model initializing and then from you loading your data. it would be nice to know how big your data.json file is.
image generation model uses alot of memory. From my personal experience, when using SD2.0 I recall that the memory went up around 23GB. The memory consumption increases as the model gets larger but also from the image size.
I recommend you try reduce the image size. Try starting with either 256/512/768 and increase it gradually if you dont get any memory allocation error.
hope this helps.

The size of data.json is irrelevant because I generate image one-by-one. I'm trying to find a way to reduce the memory usage or clarify that the high memory usage is legit and normal.

I think this is normal, you can expect any user pc for only 512 x 512 ai image

um okay, i would say that stable diffusion takes up alot of memory. did you try reduce the output image size?
